# Close button for clearing the text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a form with textbox and a button as follows:

```
   <input name="search" type="text" />
   <button class="close" id="markclick" style="position:absolute"></button>

<script>
$('#markclick').click(function()
{

 $('.name').val('');
}
</script>
```

when I click on button, it is clearing the textbox but one thing is , how do I enable the button only on typing a text in textbox?
Any input on this?

Comment: `$('.name')` ==> `$('[name="search"]')`

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/n0cfdxup/8/

Answer (score 1):

This should work even if the user pastes text in the input box.

[Link to fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/049oq8z0/4/)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#searchBox').on("change keyup paste", function() {
    $('.close').toggle($('#searchBox').val() != '');
  });

  $('#markClick').click(function() {
    $('#searchBox').val('').trigger('change');
  });
})
```

```css
.close {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="searchBox" name="search" type="text" />
<button class="close" id="markClick">X</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('[name=search]').on('keyup',function(){
    ($('[name=search]').val().trim().length == 0 )? 
    $('#markclick').attr('disabled','disabled') :
    $('#markclick').removeAttr('disabled');
}).trigger('keyup');


$('#markclick').on('click',function(){
    $('[name=search]').val('').trigger('keyup');
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/p666ncoe/1/

Answer (score 0):

Use [`.toggle`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) to play with the `display` property of the element And `input` event to handle change in the input value.

> `.toggle(Boolean)` Display or hide the matched elements.

---

> The DOM `input` event is fired synchronously when the value of an `<input>` or `<textarea>` element is changed.[[Ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/input)]

*Note:* `button` should be `display:none` initially. or use `.trigger('input')` to invoke `input` handler.

```js
$('[name="search"]').on('input', function() {
  $('#markclick').toggle(!!this.value); //return true if value!=''
});
$('#markclick').on('click', function() {
  $('[name="search"]').val('');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name="search" type="text" />
<br>
<button class="close" id="markclick" style="position:absolute;display:none">Clear</button>
```